# Custom keyboard shortcut for right click context menu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, nautilus, customization

I wish to add a custom keyboard shortcut to access the right-click context menu. Is this a possibility?

Comment: there is menu button on keyboard.. is this not useful?

Comment: Or if you really want custom shortcut for this you may create a shortcut for this command `xdotool key Menu` https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq1wf.gif

Answer (score 4):

If your keyboard comes with a ["menu" key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) (<kbd>≣</kbd>), then you can press it to simulate a right click. The menu key usually looks like this:

[image]
(Image source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kontextmen%C3%BC.jpg))

Alternatively, you can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> combintion.